# Как правильно прописать путь в background-image?

Tags: html, css, laravel

Проект написан на ларавель resources/views/welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ggg">gggg</div>
    <img src="images/earth.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Проект написан на ларавель, не могу понять что не так ? background-image не срабатывает, а в теге img все загружается.
П.С.:  адресс на ссылку с интернета отрабатывает нормально, нужно разобраться с путем внутри проекта

Файл bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css:

```
.ggg {
    background-image: url("images/earth.png");   // пробовал еще и так     url(images/earth.png)  url('images/earth.png')
    height: 200px;
}
```